# Getting single entrances from a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these two tables:

```
stores:
+----------+--------------+
| store_id | store_number |
+----------+--------------+
|        1 |          231 |
|        2 |          132 |
|        3 |          321 |
+----------+--------------+

entrances:
+-------------+----------+-----------------+
| entrance_id | store_id | entrance_number |
+-------------+----------+-----------------+
|           1 |        1 |               1 |
|           2 |        1 |               2 |
|           3 |        2 |               1 |
|           4 |        3 |               1 |
|           5 |        3 |               2 |
|           6 |        3 |               3 |
+-------------+----------+-----------------+
```

The `entrance_number` is a sequence number for each store starting on `1`. What I want to do is `JOIN` these two tables and then add `1` to the `entrance_number` so I get the next `entrance_number` for each store.

Like this:

```
SELECT
    store_number,
    entrance_number + 1
FROM
    stores
JOIN
    entrances
ON
    stores.store_id = entrances.store_id
```

which gives this result:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| store_number | entrance_number |
+--------------+-----------------+
|          231 |               2 |
|          231 |               3 |
|          132 |               2 |
|          321 |               2 |
|          321 |               3 |
|          321 |               4 |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

What I want is getting the single top entrance_number for each store so the result is this:

```
+--------------+-----------------+
| store_number | entrance_number |
+--------------+-----------------+
|          231 |               3 |
|          132 |               2 |
|          321 |               4 |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Which gives the next `entrance_number` for each store.

How can I use `JOIN` to get this "single entrance" from entrance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply `Group By` and `Max`.

```
 SELECT
        store_number,
        max(entrance_number + 1)
    FROM
        stores
    JOIN
        entrances
    ON
        stores.store_id = entrances.store_id
        group by store_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
                select store_number,entrance_number from
                ( SELECT
                store_number,
                (entrance_number)+1 AS 'entrance_number ',
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY store_number ORDER BY entrance_number DESC ) AS RankID
                 FROM
                stores S
                JOIN
                entrances E
                ON
                S.store_id = E.store_id    
                )a
                where RankID='1'  -- here You can change RankID as per requirement like for top entrance use 1 or 2nd top use 2
```

Using MAX and Group by :

```
            SELECT
            store_number,
            MAX(entrance_number) + 1 AS 'entrance_number '
            FROM
            stores S
            JOIN
            entrances E
            ON
             S.store_id = E.store_id
             GROUP BY store_number
```